# c3p0 connection pool cannot change database

Tags: java, netbeans, c3p0

i am running a web app where 3 databases are involved
the first database is the admin database and the two other databases are for two separate institutions,
meaning both institutions are using the same app but can access their separate database per a unique_code entered.
the databases are starter(admin database),company1 and company2.

when the web app is started, the admin database is initially connected to automatically. (starter database).
(first connection pool) code below: which works perfectly.

```
comboPooledDataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
comboPooledDataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://host.com/starter");
comboPooledDataSource.setUser("username");
comboPooledDataSource.setPassword("password");                       
comboPooledDataSource.setMinPoolSize(2);
comboPooledDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(3000);
comboPooledDataSource.setAcquireIncrement(1);
comboPooledDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(1800);
comboPooledDataSource.setMaxStatements(0);
comboPooledDataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(3);
comboPooledDataSource.setBreakAfterAcquireFailure(false);
comboPooledDataSource.setUnreturnedConnectionTimeout(5);
```

and the user must enter a code in a textfield on the homepage (like a login).
if the code exist in the starter database, the database related to the code is connected to and the user can view their contents from that database.
//code to fetch database name is written below: which also works successfully

```
String entry_code=request.getParameter("Ecode");
 //where 'Ecode' is the name of the html textfield where the user types the code
 try{
 con=Main_C3Po_Connection.getInstance().getConnection();
 String sql="select db from checker where code='"+entry_code+"'";
 pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
 rs=pst.executeQuery();
 if(rs.next()){
get_db=rs.getString("db");
 }
 
 }catch(SQLException e){
 out.println(e);
 }
```

eg: starter(admin database)
table name : **checker**
id  | code |         db      |
11  |   44   |  company1 |
12  |   35   |  company2 |
so the second connection pool doesnt have a fixed database url but a variable database name.

```
eg:("jdbc:mysql://host.com/"+get_db+"?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes");
```

where **get_db** is the variable name.
so when the user enters code 44, the value in the db column relating to the code entered is (company1), is then placed into the **get_db** variable and the database is connected to and can be accessed.

when the first code(44) is entered, the '**company1**' value is placed into the '**get_db**' variable and the connection is made successfully.

but the problem is after logging out and the second code (35) is entered, the 'company2' value is also placed into the 'get_db' variable BUT
the connection pool for some reason still keeps the previous database connection and **cannot switch to the other database chosen**.
below is the second connection pool which cannot switch to a different database, though the database variable is changed:

```
comboPooledDataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
comboPooledDataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://host.com/"+get_db+"?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes");
comboPooledDataSource.setUser("username");
comboPooledDataSource.setPassword("password");
comboPooledDataSource.setMinPoolSize(2);
comboPooledDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(3000);
comboPooledDataSource.setAcquireIncrement(1);
comboPooledDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(1800);
comboPooledDataSource.setMaxStatements(0);
comboPooledDataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(5);
comboPooledDataSource.setBreakAfterAcquireFailure(false);
comboPooledDataSource.setUnreturnedConnectionTimeout(5);
```

please how do i configure the second connection pool to kill all connections after logging out so that it can **switch** and access any other database chosen. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an awkward configuration; I don't recommend it. But it should work. The act of calling

```
comboPooledDataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://host.com/"+get_db+"?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes");
```

should cause a "soft reset", so any new `Connection`s you get from the pool will be to the new DB. Are you sure that you are not still using the old `Connection`? That is, have you been sure to `close()` all `Connection` objects from before the change?

A less awkward approach would just be to make multiple `Connection` pools, one for each database you need to access. When you are done with a `Connection` pool, free the threads and `Connection`s associated with it by calling `close()` on the pool itself.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the issue. i have all my queries `close()`ed in a `finally block` after each query but the problem still persist. i also attempted writing `comboPooledDataSource.close()` in a finally block after the  connection pool configuration `try-catch block` but was also unable to open any further connections because i had an exception saying `con is null`. please how do i properly close all connections safely and still get to open connections when the app is runned. thank you.

Comment: please direct on how to `close()` the connection pool as i commented above @SteveWaldman. thank you

Comment: it's best to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure prompt connection closure. robust use of finally directly is a bit trickier than it looks.

Comment: after `comboPooledDataSource.close()`, the `DataSource` is dead. you should then construct a new one, with your new jdbcUrl, before trying to acquire more Connections.